# On passing a DateTime? variable to a method, compiler says it cannot covert a null value to a DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, arguments, nullable

I have a TextBox control, which is supposed to store a date. As long as the date is not a required field in my page (I'm using Web Forms), I am passing a DateTime? (nullable), not a DateTime variable to a method that connects to the database and inserts the appropriate value. It looks something like this.

```
public void DatabaseMethod(DateTime? myDate)
{
// Insert the appropriate value into the database
}

// I'm calling the above method like this:
DatabaseMethod(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtContractMyDate.Text) ? null : Convert.ToDateTime(txtContractMyDate.Text));
```

I am getting a message from the compiler that goes like **"Type of conditional statement cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'null' and 'System.DateTime'".**

I can just do the following:

```
DateTime? myDate = null;

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtContractMyDate.Text))
{
    myDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtContractStornoDate.Text);
}
```

And then call the method like:

```
DatabaseMethod(myDate);
```

And of course, that is okay, but I just can't figure out why I'm getting the stated message from the compiler (**"Type of conditional statement cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'null' and 'System.DateTime'"**).

Comment: Or search for "Type of conditional statement cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between" for many, many others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast `null` to `DateTime?`

```
DatabaseMethod(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtContractMyDate.Text) ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(txtContractMyDate.Text)
```

Comment: Never directly use `Convert.ToDateTime` be defensive coder and use TryParse()

Comment: Yup, you're right about TryParse(), but I decided to use Convert.ToDateTime directly, just because I have a RegularExpressionValidator and a jquery DatePicker on the page, and posting a wrong value to the server is impossible (or I think so).